# If David was only the ninth generation after a bastard ancestor, how was he allowed to enter the Assembly of the LORD?

Tags: contradiction, deuteronomy

In the last verses of [Genesis 38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=genesis%2038&version=ESV), Judah has a bastard son with Tamar, named Perez, and according to [Matthew 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=matthew%201&version=ESV), David is the ninth generation after Perez.

But according to [Deuteronomy 23:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=deuteronomy%2023&version=ESV), if someone is a bastard, only his 11th generation will be permitted to enter the assembly of the LORD.

Assuming David entered the assembly of the Lord, these passages are difficult to reconcile, what's it that I'm missing here?